# Printing a LinkedList in Java without toString

Tags: java, list, linked-list

What is the simplest way to print the `LinkedList` `result` to make sure my code is doing what I want it to? toString seems complicated because you have to write more code it seems. Please show a syntax example, thank you.

UPDATE: I was able to figure the answer out on my own which is a simple `System.out.println(result);` which is odd because I had previously tried the line of code that it needed, maybe it was placed incorrectly. I updated the post with an answer in case it can help others down the road.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Two {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Queue<Integer>firstQ=new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Queue<Integer>secondQ=new LinkedList<Integer>();

        firstQ.add(3);
        firstQ.add(7);
        firstQ.add(9);
        firstQ.add(11);
        firstQ.add(15);

        secondQ.add(5);
        secondQ.add(12);
        secondQ.add(17);

        mergeQueues(firstQ,secondQ);
    }
    public static Queue<Integer>mergeQueues(Queue<Integer>firstQ,Queue<Integer>secondQ)
    {
        Queue<Integer>result=new LinkedList<Integer>();
        while(!firstQ.isEmpty()){
            int a=firstQ.remove();
            result.add(a);
            if(!secondQ.isEmpty()){
                int b=secondQ.remove();
                    result.add(b);
            }
        }
        while(!secondQ.isEmpty()){
            int c=secondQ.remove();
                result.add(c);

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(result);`?

Comment: @Radiodef tried it, doesn't work

Comment: @SeumasFrew What result do you get when you try that?

Comment: Please explain to us the problem you are having then. Tell us what the output is, explain to us why it's wrong and show us the complete code that reproduces that output.

Comment: @col6y Nothing, the code executes fine without any errors but fails to print the list

Comment: Well never mind, it works now. Really odd. Closing question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Two {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Queue<Integer>firstQ=new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Queue<Integer>secondQ=new LinkedList<Integer>();

        firstQ.add(3);
        firstQ.add(7);
        firstQ.add(9);
        firstQ.add(11);
        firstQ.add(15);

        secondQ.add(5);
        secondQ.add(12);
        secondQ.add(17);

        mergeQueues(firstQ,secondQ);
    }
    public static Queue<Integer>mergeQueues(Queue<Integer>firstQ,Queue<Integer>secondQ)
    {
        Queue<Integer>result=new LinkedList<Integer>();
        while(!firstQ.isEmpty()){
            int a=firstQ.remove();
            result.add(a);
            if(!secondQ.isEmpty()){
                int b=secondQ.remove();
                    result.add(b);
            }
        }
        while(!secondQ.isEmpty()){
            int c=secondQ.remove();
                result.add(c);

        }
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```